# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Scrapy (python)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm installing Scrapy in Linux in mode root user:

```
pip install Scrapy
Collecting Scrapy
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Scrapy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Scrapy
```

How else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me (root user):

python -m pip install Scrapy